# Automapper : how to eleminate repetitive mapping?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, automapper, poco

I have following structure for tables. The two tables have a lot of common properties over 20 im just listing a two. Also I have 10 tables similar to this. This is how the tables are in the database. There is over 10 concrete tables with similar properties and are not connected to each other in any way. I am using POCO generator to generate the classes from my database.

```
public class A
 {
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string address {get;set;}
    public string AId {get;set;}
  }

public class B
 {
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string address {get;set;}
    public string BId {get;set;}
  }
```

I have following viewModels:

```
public class BaseViewModel
 {
    public string Fullname {get;set;}
    public string Fulladdress {get;set;}
   }

public class AviewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
    public string AId {get;set;}
  }

public class BViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
     public string BId {get;set;}
  }
```

when I create mapping i have to repeat all this for each viewModel that I have created.

```
config.CreateMap<A, AviewModel>()
.ForMember(dest => Fulladdress, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>.address))
.ForMember(dest => Fullname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>.name)).ReverseMap();


config.CreateMap<B, BviewModel>()
.ForMember(dest => Fulladdress, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>.address))
.ForMember(dest => Fullname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>.name)).ReverseMap();
```

Is it possible to reduce the repetitive mappings that I might potentially have to do ?

Comment: Why don't you extract and use base class for your entities, similar to what you are doing for your view models.

Comment: @IvanStoev so I am using POCO generated classes I dont want to change anything in classes manually. So that means every-time some one updates the .tt file my construct of the  is gone.

Comment: actually you are right seems to be the best solution

Comment: Lol, good to hear that after working on non base class solution.

Comment: lol i just looked at your new answer, that may be an easier solution. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the common mapping code to a helper generic method. You will constrain the `TDestination` type to be a class derived from `BaseViewModel`, thus allowing to access the destination members in `ForMember` method. And for source mapping you will use the `MapFrom` overload accepting `string` property name:

```
public static class CommonMappings
{
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> MapToBaseViewModel<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map)
        where TDestination : BaseViewModel
    {
        return map
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Fulladdress, opt => opt.MapFrom("address"))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Fullname, opt => opt.MapFrom("name"));
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
config.CreateMap<A, AViewModel>()
    .MapToBaseViewModel()
    // ... specific mappings
    .ReverseMap();

config.CreateMap<B, BViewModel>()
    .MapToBaseViewModel()
    // ... specific mappings
    .ReverseMap();
```

**Update:** It turns out that automatic reverse mapping in the latest at this time AutoMapper 6.1.1 works for the lambda overload of `MapFrom`, but not for the `string` overload (in AutoMapper 5 it doesn't work at all). So until it gets fixed, you can use the following `MapFrom(string)` replacement:

```
public static class AMExtensions
{
    public static void From<TSource, TDestination, TMember>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource, TDestination, TMember> opt, string name)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "src");
        var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, name);
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
        opt.MapFrom((dynamic)selector);
    }
}
```

Which means you'll need to replace `MapFrom` calls in the original solution with `From`, because we can't give the extension method the same name since it has less priority than the concrete interface method.

Probably too much effort compared to base class approach. But useful in case you can't control the design of the entity classes.

Comment: This is working too, so I created a base class outside my POCO generated classes and configured it to ignore the common fields and inherit from my base class. That is actually really good I did that. I will still use this commonMapping class for other small repetitive mappings. Thanks A lot !!

Comment: While smart, this is more of a hack :) I would only use this when really there is no way to make a source base class/interface.

Comment: yes, I was also just testing it a bit more and it seems that reverseMap() does not work for it? It gets the data but does not post for me ?

Comment: @hamadkh You are right. But the same happens with your original (repetitive) code, so this approach is not breaking anything.

Comment: Wow, the previous comment is true for AM version 5, but in AM 6 automatic reverse mapping work for other methods using the lambda `MapFrom`, and doesn't work for `string` "MapFrom` :( Eh Jimmy, Jimmy -why...

Answer (score 2):

You need a base class for the source classes. You create a map between the base source class and the destination class. You include that map in the map for the derived classes. That would allow you to reuse the configuration. [The docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance). For simple cases you can use As instead of Include.

Answer (score 0):

You set an attribute on properties on your models.
This contains the name of the property it maps from on a source object.

Then you make a generic method that accepts the target object and source object, that finds the customattribute on the property where the attribute was set, and the property on the target object (or vice versa) and then sets the value.

You can even handle nested objects by asking if its a class property or not.

Comment: So instead of duplicate fluent configuration you are suggesting duplicate data annotations (custom attributes). What's the difference - you still need to do a lot of repetitive work.

Comment: Eh no? You would only ever have to define an attribute for a property on a class once. To the source type or vice versa. Than the generic class handles the mapping for you, regards less of which class you send to the mapper. There is no repetative tasks involved.